# wpf usercontrol positioning not updating instantly while the bound TextBox does

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, viewmodel

I have 2 TextBoxes in a Usercontrol (InfoControl) bound to a Point property in a VM implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

I have another UserControl (DesignerControl) which contains a draggable rectangle.
The Rectangle has its Canvas.Left and Canvas.Bottom bound to a ConvPoint property of the same VM.
ConvPoint Property (0 => ActualWidth) is a converted version of the Point Property (0 => 1)

when i drag my rectangle, the ConvPoint VM Property and the values in the textboxes are instantly updated, but when i update my textboxes with new values, the VM Point Property is instantly updated but the Rectangle is positioned only when i drag the rectangle again and not instantly.

A bit of code to explain:

First, my ViewModel's Position Property

```cs
public class MyVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private DependencyPoint position;
    public DependencyPoint Position
    {
        get { return this.position; }
        set
        {
            this.position = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Position");
        }
    }

    public DependencyPoint ConvPosition
    {
        get { return new Point(this.Position.X * MainVM.ActualWidth, this.Position.Y * MainVM.AcutalHeight);}
        set
        {
            Point p = new Point(value.X/MainVM.ActualWidth,value.Y/MainVM.ActualHeight);
            this.position = p;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ConvPosition");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I'm using for this a class DependencyPoint to have a notification on the X and Y properties:

```cs
public class DependencyPoint : DependencyObject
{

    public enum PointOrder
    {
        isStartPoint,
        isEndPoint,
        isPoint1,
        isPoint2
    }

    public DependencyPoint()
    {
    }

    public DependencyPoint(Double x, Double y, PointOrder po)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Order = po;
    }

    public DependencyPoint(DependencyPoint point)
    {
        this.X = point.X;
        this.Y = point.Y;
        this.Order = point.Order;
    }


    public DependencyPoint(Point point, PointOrder po)
    {
        this.X = point.X;
        this.Y = point.Y;
        this.Order = po;
    }

    public Point ToPoint()
    {
        return new Point(this.X, this.Y);
    }



    public PointOrder Order
    {
        get { return (PointOrder)GetValue(OrderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Order.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Order", typeof(PointOrder), typeof(DependencyPoint), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    public Double X
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for X.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(Double), typeof(DependencyPoint), new UIPropertyMetadata((double)0.0));



    public Double Y
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Y.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(Double), typeof(DependencyPoint), new UIPropertyMetadata((double)0.0));
}
```

then in my InfoControl:

```cs
<Grid Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Position}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DockPanel Margin="3,3,0,1" Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="2,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="StartPoint.X :"/>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="Black" Background="#efefef" Width="Auto" Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource StDConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Margin="3,3,0,1" Grid.Row="1" LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="2,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="StartPoint.Y :"/>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="Black" Background="#efefef" Width="Auto" Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource StDConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
```

And in the DesignerControl:

```cs
<UserControl>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Point" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Bottom="{Binding ConvPosition.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Left="{Binding ConvPosition.X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I have access to the actualWidth and my Rectangle is well positioned in the Canvas.

I know my properties in the VM or a bit dirty but i don't know an other way to do it properly and manage the conversion too.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because ConvPosition depends from Position you should raise a NotificationChanged for ConvPosition in Position setter.

```
public Point Position
{
    get { return this.position; }
    set
    {
        this.position = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Position");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ConvPosition");
    }
}
```

ConvPosition you can change to this

```
public Point ConvPosition
{
    get { return new Point(this.Position.X * MainVM.ActualWidth, this.Position.Y * MainVM.AcutalHeight); }
    set
    {
        this.Position = new Point(value.X/MainVM.ActualWidth, value.Y/MainVM.ActualHeight);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think two additional properties in MyVM would be the simpliest solution.

```
public double X
{
    get { return Position.X; }
    set
    {
        Position = new Point(value, Position.Y);
        RaisePropertyChanged("X");
    }
}

public double Y
{
    get { return Position.Y; }
    set
    {
        Position = new Point(Position.X, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
    }
}
```

Only change in Grid:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
```

Comment: aarh this answer seemed perfect, but unfortunately, it's not working.
i'm so lost now...

Comment: I think the last problem is: [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk9hwzbw) is a Structure. It does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Use a (own) class that does or maybe create in your class `MyVM` two further properties `X` and `Y` that creates for every change a new Point Position. Bind the TextBoxes to these.

Comment: i've tried the class which implements INotifyPRopertyChanged, that's my DependencyPoint class, 'cause i could not indeed propagate my points values. That's why i'm stuck here (sorry, it's been a while since i'm stuck on this, i forgot to mention)

Comment: You have tried replacing `Point Position` with `DependencyPoint Position` and it was not working? Can you show your DependencyPoint class?

Comment: my bad, it is a DependencyPoint, i made a wrong copy/paste, i'll edit my post and add the DependencyPoint class

Comment: I've added a working solution. Your DependencyPoint class does not notify for a new position and the necessary changes would be to elaborate for me a the moment.